# Debugging Spring Boot project with Thymeleaf in Eclipse is dead slow

Tags: eclipse, debugging, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I use Spring Boot 1.5.2 with Thymeleaf 3.03 and my IDE is the latest Spring  Tool Suite 3.8.4.
This is my first learning project. During the development I debugged several time without problem. But now I experience unacceptable runtime.
I have just 5 domain classes right now with some configuration classes, 1 service class and 5 repository interfaces. The project is very small as it is a test project.
Starting my project in debug mode needs 110 seconds on a 4 core machine.
What is even worse, it takes 6 minutes to load my index.html which has a size of 2 Mb. Did anybody experienced something similar?